# How to (effienciently) construct a string in Cython?

Tags: python, string, char, cython

I am trying to fasten my python code with cython.

In cython, one of the bottlenecks I try to remove is the construction of a filename (string) in a loop.
However, I don't manage to re write my python code in a cython way:

```
 cdef str filename, path

 for ii in range(len(a0)):
   for jj in range(len(a1)):
       filename = self.path + 'directory' + format(int(lon[ii,jj]),'02d')+ '_' + format(int(lat[ii,jj]),'02d') + '.csv'
```

Any help on how to rewrite this would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Please don't use variables like "a0", "a1", "ii" and "jj" -- they're difficult to reason about. Also you don't need to do `range(len(a0))`, if your variable is iterable just do `for ii in a0` or equivalent.

Comment: `format` is a `Python` function, as is the string `+`.  So is the `lon[ii,jj]` indexing (`numpy`).  There isn't much that `cython` can convert to 'pure' C.

Comment: A quick glance at the `cython` strings docs, http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html, suggests that it can't do much to speed up string operations.  They discourage using `c` strings.  Interfacing to a `C++` string library might work.

Comment: Are you going to be using the filename for read or write the `csv`?  My guess is that creating a filename string takes much less time than opening and use that file.  Optimizing this task is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: And the use of `format` suggests you are using Py3 and unicode strings.  Read what `cython` says about the non-support of unicode in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can speed up the formatting in Python.  For example:

```
In [67]: lat=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [68]: names=[]
In [69]: for i in range(lat.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(lat.shape[1]):
    ...:        name = 'path/'+'directory'+format(lat[i,j],'02d')+'_'+format(lat
    ...: [i,j]+3,'02d')+'.csv'
    ...:        names.append(name)
    ...:        
In [70]: names
Out[70]: 
['path/directory00_03.csv',
 'path/directory01_04.csv',
 'path/directory02_05.csv',
 'path/directory03_06.csv',
 'path/directory04_07.csv',
 'path/directory05_08.csv']
```

can be reworked as:

```
In [71]: names=[]
In [72]: fmt='path/'+'directory/'+'%02d_%02d.csv'
In [73]: for i in range(lat.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(lat.shape[1]):
    ...:        name = fmt%(lat[i,j],lat[i,j])
    ...:        names.append(name)
```

In other words, create one format string at the start, and use that repeatedly.

Or for the PY3 styles `format`:

```
fmt = 'path/directory{:02d}_{:02d}.csv'
name = fmt.format(lat[i,j],lat[i,j])
```

Quick time tests suggest a 2-3 x speedup (more with the older `%` style).